# How do I use Javascript or jQuery to set the width of <th> elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website that is dynamically pulling information, setting the column widths in JavaScript. I set the widths of the table body columns like this:

```
cell2.style.width="150px";
cell3.style.width="210px";
cell4.style.width="400px";
cell5.style.width="150px";
```

It works fine for setting up the body, but they do not line up with the table headers. The table headers are static and since the body is dynamic they are not lining up. Below is the static header:

```
<th id="top1">Name</th>
<th id="top2">Type</th>
<th id="top3">Subject</th>
<th id="top4">Target(s)</th>
```

**[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Lance_Bitner/d19bdrdw/)**

How do I give the same width values I have in the table body, to the `<th>` seen above and in my jsfiddle? I need to use JavaScript or jQuery, because it is a dynamic table and does not listen to my CSS commands, no matter what I add; not even `!important`.

Comment: Could you show a more complete example of the problem - your fiddle seems to be missing a lot of the relevant code. The JS and CSS for example

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jquery - just CSS - this will style even dynamic content.

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align:left
}

#tableTest th:nth-child(1),
#tableTest td:nth-child(1)
  {width:150px}

#tableTest th:nth-child(2),
#tableTest td:nth-child(2)
  {width:210px}


#tableTest th:nth-child(3),
#tableTest td:nth-child(3)
  {width:400px}

#tableTest th:nth-child(4),
#tableTest td:nth-child(4)
  {width:150px}
```

```html
<table id='tableTest'>
  <tr>
    <th id="top1">Name</th>
    <th id="top2">Type</th>
    <th id="top3">Subject</th>
    <th id="top4">Target(s)</th>
   </tr>
    <tr>
    <td id="cell1">1</td>
    <td id="cell2">2</td>
    <td id="cell3">3</td>
    <td id="cell4">4</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: The OP already stated that he tried with CSS, even using `!important` and did not worked.

Comment: @lonut - true - that was mentioned but since it is possible to yuse CSS to achive this 0- I assumed that the CSS that was tried was either incorrect or inefficient. :)

Answer (score 1):

Table Header **th** has an attribute **width** which can be used for width. If you want to do it with JS or JQuery. You can do it like

```
document.getElementById('top1').setAttribute('width', '10%');
```

**OR**

```
$('#top1').attr('width', '10%');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the id selectors in jQuery and use the [**width()**](http://api.jquery.com/width/) method to set the width of every `th`:

Updated **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/d19bdrdw/2/)**.

```
$('#top1').width(100);
$('#top2').width(200);
$('#top3').width(300);
$('#top4').width(100);
```

Or using **[css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)**:

```
$('#top1').css('width', '100px');
$('#top2').css('width', '200px');
$('#top3').css('width', '300px');
$('#top4').css('width', '100px');
```

Or in JS you can use:

```
document.getElementById('#top1').style.width = '100px';
document.getElementById('#top2').style.width = '200px';
document.getElementById('#top3').style.width = '300px';
document.getElementById('#top4').style.width = '100px';
```

Answer (score 1):

just use jQuery if you are using it.

```js
var data = [{
 name : "Test 1",
  type:"type1",
  subject:"subject1",
  targer:"target1"
},
{
 name : "Test 2222222222",
  type:"type2",
  subject:"subject122222",
  targer:"target2"
},
{
 name : "Test 3333333",
  type:"type13",
  subject:"subject3",
  targer:"target3333333"
}];

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#top1').css('width','150px');
$('#top2').css('width','210px');
$('#top3').css('width','400px');
$('#top4').css('width','150px');
var table = $("#notificationMgmtTableBody");
 data.forEach(function(item){
   var tr = $("<tr>");
    Object.keys(item).forEach(function(k){
       var td = $("<td>");
       td.text(item[k]);
        tr.append(td);
      });
      table.append(tr);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="queryMgmt" style="height: 400px">
  <table id="notificationMgmtTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover jupiterTable">
    <thead id="notificationMgmtTableHead" style="width: 100%">
      <tr
          style="background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, .7); color: #003366; width: 100%">
        <th id="top1">Name</th>
        <th id="top2">Type</th>
        <th id="top3">Subject</th>
        <th id="top4">Target(s)</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="notificationMgmtTableBody">       
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just select the element by ID:

```
$('#top1').css('width','150px');
```

sorry my mistake.... it's early and the end of the week!

?

Comment: surely you mean $('#top1').css('width','150px');

Comment: Or `document.getElementById('top1').style.width = "150px";`

Comment: Or `$('#top1')[0].style.width="150px";`

Answer (score 0):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d19bdrdw/3/)**

Since you're using jQuery you could use **[`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)** method :

```
$('#top1').css('width','150px');
$('#top2').css('width','210px');
$('#top3').css('width','400px');
$('#top4').css('width','150px');
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('#top1').css('width','150px');
$('#top2').css('width','210px');
$('#top3').css('width','400px');
$('#top4').css('width','150px');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="queryMgmt"  style="height: 400px">
  <table id="notificationMgmtTable"  border=1 class="table table-bordered table-hover jupiterTable">
    <thead id="notificationMgmtTableHead" style="width: 100%">
      <tr style="background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, .7); color: #003366; width: 100%">
        <th id="top1">Name</th>
        <th id="top2">Type</th>
        <th id="top3">Subject</th>
        <th id="top4">Target(s)</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="notificationMgmtTableBody">    
      <tr>
        <td>Name 1</td>
        <td>Type 1</td>
        <td>Subject 1</td>
        <td>Target(s) 1</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To show a jQuery approach although as above - it is not required. You can set the desired widths into an array and then using jQuery - assign them to the th's and td's.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var widths = [150,210,400,150];
  
  $('#tableTest th, #tableTest td').each(function(idx){
    $(this).css('width',widths[idx]+'px');
  })
})
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align:left
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='tableTest'>
  <tr>
    <th id="top1">Name</th>
    <th id="top2">Type</th>
    <th id="top3">Subject</th>
    <th id="top4">Target(s)</th>
   </tr>
    <tr>
    <td id="cell1">1</td>
    <td id="cell2">2</td>
    <td id="cell3">3</td>
    <td id="cell4">4</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
```